# Duplicate entry in database on refreshing the submitted form in django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

After i submit my form using GET method and then refresh the page the data get resubmitted
i am using javascript for form validation

my views are:

```
def show(request,post_id):
    try:
        p = post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        c = comment.objects.filter(blog_id=p)
        if 'cbox' in request.GET:
            c = comment(text=request.GET['cbox'],name=request.GET['cname'],blog=p)
            c.save()
        c_list = comment.objects.filter(blog_id=p)   
    except  post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response('show.html',{'post':p,'c_list':c_list})
```

my form is:

```
<form  name="comment" action="" method="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    <input id="carea"  type="text" placeholder="leave a comment" name="cbox" >
    <input id="cb"  type="submit"  value="Post" />
    <input id="cn"  type="text"  placeholder="Name" name="cname">
</form>
```

i want that when i refresh my page my data should not get resubmited
thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: i am using GET method here

Comment: In Django tutorial 4 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial04/ , `Using method="post" (as opposed to method="get") is very important, because the act of submitting this form will alter data server-side. Whenever you create a form that alters data server-side, use method="post". This tip isn't specific to Django; it's just good Web development practice.`

Comment: okhay i will surely keep it in mind
is there any way o solve above problem using 'GET' method?

Comment: No. Don't use GET for adding content to your db. 

Proper way of solving this is to use "POST" and redirect on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really insist on using GET to submit which practically is not a good method. You should do a request redirect using HttpResponseRedirect from the server side which will remove the query string from the url . This way it wouldn't resumit the form.

```
def show(request,post_id):
    try:
        p = post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
        c = comment.objects.filter(blog_id=p)
        if 'cbox' in request.GET:
            c = comment(text=request.GET['cbox'],name=request.GET['cname'],blog=p)
            c.save()
            #Do a redirect here 
            return HttpResponseRedirect("URL of the page you would like to redirect")
        c_list = comment.objects.filter(blog_id=p)   
    except  post.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
    return render_to_response('show.html',{'post':p,'c_list':c_list})
```